# Как дообучить обученную нейросеть?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Есть обученная нейронная сеть. Требуется произвести её дообучение на новом датасете.

**Архитектура сети:**

```
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.001,
                           patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto')
chkpt = ModelCheckpoint('architecture.hdf5', 
                        monitor='val_loss', 
                        verbose=1, 
                        save_best_only=True, 
                        mode='auto')
callbacks = [early_stop, chkpt]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 32))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)) 
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=50,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks)
```

**PS:**
Как можно улучшить архитектуру данной нейросети?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По идее все должно получиться если просто прочитать с диска сохраненную модель и продолжить обучение:

```
from keras.models import save_model, load_model

model = load_model(model_filename)
model.fit(new_x_train, new_y_train, ...)
```

---

PS я не был уверен сохраняется ли `learning rate` оптимизатора во время сохранения модели. Некоторые оптимизаторы уменьшают `шаг обучения` / `realning rate` чтобы начинать градиентный спуск с большим шагом (для более быстрой сходимости) и уменьшать его в процессе работы, чтобы не проскочить минимум (при слишком большом шаге градиентный спуск может не сойтись). Проверил на обученной ранее и сохраненной модели - `learning rate` сохраняется и читается `load_model()`:

```
In [11]: model = load_model(model_fn)

In [12]: import keras.backend as K

In [13]: K.eval(model.optimizer.lr)
Out[13]: 1e-04
```

при начале обучения `learning rate` был равен `1e-02`

Comment: Да, всё работает